# How do I use Twitter Bootstrap with Ruby on Rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm switching from PHP to Ruby on Rails and I'm loving it, the only thing is I'm so used to Twitter Bootstrap for most of my designs and now I feel crippled without it, I followed some tutorials like adding `bootstrap-sass` and what not to my `Gemfile`, but I still appear to be missing important things like `input-block-level` I'm just curious if there is an updated version or a easier tutorial to follow? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add bootstrap to your application.js and application.css? As detailed here https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#usage.

Comment: you can add twitter bootstrap to your rails application as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, the easiest and most rails way to integrate the twitter bootstrap to rails is via

[`twitter-bootstrap-rails`](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem, they have a pretty good documentation too.

check these [screen casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics), and [this (premium)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/329-more-on-twitter-bootstrap) to get an idea.

and welcome to Rails :)

Answer (score 0):

To to the `input-block-level` in ERB do something like this

```
"input-block-level" => "hello_world"
```

Comment: I have this, <%= f.text_field :name, class: "input-block-level" %>

Answer (score 0):

Same as you, I'm coming from PHP and love RoR ;)

With bootstrap you need to import it in your manifest. Read a bit about the assets pipeline in RoR guide.

To import bootstrap, create a file in your app/assets/stylesheets directory, with the name you want, but with the extension .css.scss, and place in it the following line:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Also if you need to use the javascript helpers from bootstrap, you need to add the following line in your app/assets/javascript/application.js file:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

Just download the bootstrap ( CSS, JS ) file and make the updation in that file at regular interval from his official site : [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

For Bootstrap Tutorials : [Click Here](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/tutorial.php)

Or you can refer the sample code for reference, because sometimes we dnt get the way to implement such functionality like tooltip.

Comment: The original query how to use bootstrap in ruby on rails not the user is asking for Bootstrap tutorial.